# How to know If marker crossed polygon on google map

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, webforms, polygon

I am trying to locate the iPad location. Where as goal is to get alert when user who carrying the iPad should be inside polygon always. How to get alert if provided latitude and longitude crossing the polygon. Any reference link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use geofence,put a circle on the map set radius and give a condition if its out give a alert.

Comment: any reference link, that I could refer?

Comment: i am not sure about this hope it helps you http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/geofences.html